# How do people name the $(this) when it's used within code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#detailData')
    .on('change', '.updatable', function () {
        var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
        updateField(entity, $(this), type);
        return false;
    })
```

I would like to add to the code and use `$(this)` multiple times. To make it clear, I want to assign `this` to a variable. When I use jQuery I've seen people place a `$` before the variable name. Am I correct in saying the following is correct?

```
var $abc = $('#abc');
```

If that's correct then how should I name `$(this)` which if I am understanding correctly points to a DOM variable. Also is there any difference between a DOM variable and what's returned with `$('#abc')`?

Comment: Name it however you want as long as it makes sense. `var $this` is just as valid as `var $element` as `var element` as `var elem`.

Comment: our convention at work would have it called `$this`.

Comment: I usually name it $me or $t ... Name it 'foo' or 'bar' if you are mentally more confortable "with this" `:p` As long as you know what it refers to ...

Answer (score 7):

Using `$this` to store `$(this)` is just a code *convention*, used to remind the programmer that the variable in question is *already* a jQuery object rather then a pure DOM element.

It helps avoid the common mistake of writing:

```
var foo = $(...);
$(foo).doSomething();
```

The mistake is harmless, but causes slightly inefficient code.

Conversely, using `$foo` also reminds the programmer that they can't call native DOM functions directly on that variable, and should use `$foo[n]` or `$foo.get(n)` to access the enclosed DOM element(s) instead.

Also, don't forget that since `this` *is* just a pure DOM element you can (and should) use native DOM functions or properties when appropriate:

```
var type = this.id.split('_')[1];
```

Comment: If I was to write var $this = $(this); would it then be valid to write: $this.attr('id').split('_')[1];  ?

Comment: @Marilou it would, but see my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is pretty common, but it is entirely up to you.  Consistency is the most important thing.

Comment: Would it make sense to write $inputField = $(this)

Comment: @Marilou no, you should just use `$this` for that, and _only_ use it to store `$(this)`.

Comment: if this refers to an inputField, yes it would.. the $ is just a convention to tell it's already a jquery object like Alnitak said. `$this` tells me less then `$inputField`

Comment: @Alnitak I'd argue `$inputField` is a more valuable variable name than `$this`.  It helps whoever is reading the code figure out what purpose `$this` element actually serves.

Comment: @Dennis I disagree.  The semantics of `this` in a callback handler are very well defined (i.e. the element currently being interacted with) and any programmer confused by using `$this` instead of `$inputField` isn't one I'd hire.

Comment: There is a difference between not confusing someone and making your code as easy as possible for someone who didn't write your code to read it.

Comment: @Dennis and specifically, if the native DOM element (`this`) is going to be used as well as `$this` then it would be preferable that they both have the same name

Comment: @Dennis in that situation I would likely do `var inputField = this, $inputField = $(this)`.  I would never mix `$inputField` and `this`.

Comment: @Alnitak - Note that (although not applicable to the code in the question) you may want to save a reference to the `$(this)` from the current scope for use from the containing scope. Or for use in a nested closure or something. I realise that's probably getting a bit off the track here, but still it's a good example of when you probably wouldn't name the variable `$this`. (Having said that, I _do_ use `$this` when the purpose is just to save re-creating the jQuery object.)

Comment: @nnnnnn yup, that would be a case for `var that = this, $that = $(this)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn you mean when you have an ajax call or something var self = this; $.post(somewhere,something,function(answer){ //this is overwriten, but self lives on?

Comment: @SparK - Yes, that was what I meant by "use in a nested closure". (Though I'd probably say "shadowed" rather than "overwritten".)

Answer (score 0):

```
 //jQuery to jQuery object
 $myvar = $(this);

 //jQuery to JavaScript HTML object
 var myVar = $(this)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of:

var $this = $(this);

Is normally when the function invokes multiple separate calls to the object in the context of this. The idea is that by having to fetch this dom object once is a performance cost as Jquery will rescan the dom for the required object. By assigning the object to the local scope the cost of reusing $this over $(this) is less.

It just so happens that using $this as the local variable name is a common naming scheme for most developers.

```
$('#detailData').on('change', '.updatable', function (){
    var $this = $(this),
        type = $this.attr('id').split('_')[1];
    updateField(entity, $this, type);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: the code is right, the explanation is useless.  The browser doesn't have to "rescan" the DOM every time you write `$(this)` - it just (re)creates a jQuery object containing that specific element.

Comment: ok so re-instantiate would be a better word to use - The idea was that  there is a performance cost/benefit.

Comment: and I never said it was "the browser"

Comment: @AlexP you meant Sizzle won't have to look for the element ;)

Comment: @SparK my point was that if you already have a reference to a DOM element then Sizzle / jQuery / the browser doesn't have to "look for" or "scan" anything - it just wraps the existing DOM element reference in a jQuery object.

Comment: @Alnitak yes, it's better to already have the object stored than having to capture it again